# How AWS resources limit and usage are calculated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, documentation

Going through the [AWS Service Limits documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html), I can't understand how the AWS resources usage is calculated. Does it decrease every time you launch a new instance? Does it increase when you terminate it? Is it a monthly limit? Annual?

The AWS documentation is unclear.

**Update:**

In many regions, I have Running On-Demand EC2 instances (max number of EC2s limit is 0).

In other regions I have some instances types limit equal to 0.

In other regions, I have **instance type limit > Running On-Demand EC2 instances**.

Am I missing something?

Comment: To which particular limit are you referring? That page lists hundreds of limits, each of which could be calculated differently.

Comment: EC2, to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is anytime limit, not monthly or annual. Suppose your limit is 20 EC2 instances, at any time you can have a max of 20 instances (**running + stopped**).

When you **launch** a new instance, your instance count (running + stopped) is checked and only if it is less than 20 (your limit) AWS will continue to launch a new instance. Otherwise you will get a message to increase the limit and no instance is launched.

So your limit is checked when you launch a new instance.

```
(Current running + stopped) + 1 >  instance_limit  ==> Cannot launch
(Current running + stopped) + 1 <= instance_limit  ==> Launched
```

This limit is per region and per instance type.

Comment: Okay, good. 
In many regions, I have Running On-Demand EC2 instances (max number of EC2s limit is equal to 0). In other regions I have some instances types limit equal to 0. 
In other regions, I have instance type limit > Running On-Demand EC2 instances.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon EC2 Management Console has a [Amazon EC2 Service Limits Report](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/06/19/amazon-ec2-service-limits-report-now-available/) section that displays the *current* limits on EC2 resources.

The **Running On-Demand EC2 instances** limit is described as:

> The total number of **running** On-Demand instances that you can have in this region. Some instance types have different limits for this region that count against your total limit; these are listed below. Check the Current Limit column to find out how many instances per instance type you can run.

The limits can be increased by clicking the **Request limit increase** link and providing a use-case. AWS Customer Service then evaluates the case and adjusts the limits accordingly.

In some situations, customers request a **decrease** of their limit to avoid accidentally using some of the more-expensive instance types, or to prevent instances from running in unwanted Regions.